# Terraform: how to pass instances created from different module to single widget metric in cloudwatch dashboard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, dashboard

how to pass instances created from different module to single widget metric in cloudwatch dashboard

Using below code i can able to create cloudwatch dashboard and widget ,problem is I have different ec2 modules  and they have separate outputs ( for instance ids ) while running below code i am getting different widget for each of them. But i want a single widget for them.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "main" {
  dashboard_name = "sample_dashboard"
  dashboard_body = <<EOF
{
  "widgets": [
    ${templatefile("${path.module}/cpu.tmpl", { ids = toset([for instance in module.ec2-aaa: instance.aaa-instance-ID]) })},
    ${templatefile("${path.module}/cpu.tmpl", { ids = toset([for instance in module.ec2-bbb: instance.bbb-instance-ID]) })}
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

cpu.tmpl

```
{
  "type": "metric",
  "x": 0,
  "y": 0,
  "width": 12,
  "height": 6,
  "properties": {
    "metrics": ${jsonencode([for id in ids : ["AWS/EC2","CPUUtilization","InstanceId", "${id}"]])},
    "period": 300,
    "stat": "Average",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "title": "EC2 Instance CPU"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to combine those module outputs or concatenate them while passing as input to widget ?

Answer (score 1):

used setunion to merge these outputs from different modules and its working as expected.

```
{
  "widgets": [
    ${templatefile("${path.module}/cpu.tmpl", { ids = setunion( toset([for instance in module.ec2-aaa: instance.aaa-instance-ID]) , toset([for instance in module.ec2-bbb: instance.bbb-instance-ID]) ) })}
  ]
}
```